# woocommerce dynamic pricing hide regular price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using dynamic pricing plugin to configure products price based on the role. It works fine from the functionality perspective. But it displays both the regular price and the configured price on the screen. I am wondering that is there a way to hide the regular price and only shows the configured price? 
[image]
(With the regular price that's more like a discount or products on sale but they are not. They are just the actual price for a certain role. )

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you, if you are using Woo-commerce plugin:

1. Go to woocommerce plugin &copy the templates folder & paste in your theme folder.
2. Rename that templates folder name with woocommerce name in your theme folder.
3. open the newly named templates folder i.e. woocommerce folder & go to loop folder & open the price.php file & comment the code according to your requirement. This will hide price on the products page.
4. Now open the single-product folder & open the price.php file & comment the code according to your requirement. This will hide the price tag on your single product page.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div that is displaying the deleted price.

```
p.price>del>span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hide regular price from woocommerce. Add to additional CSS.

```
   .price>del>span:nth-child(1)
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
```